# How to slice and access text with TkInter's indices?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

In Python, to slice a string to use indices, e.g.

```
word = "Python" # immutable string
word[2:5]  # characters from position 2 (included) to 5 (excluded)
```

outputs `'tho'`

The Text Widget for TkInter outputs text location at

```
line.char
```

which indicates the *char'th* character on *line* line.

If I input a simple text file into a Text Widget GUI as follows:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

filename = "textfile1.txt"

with open(filename, "rt", encoding='latin1') as in_file:
    readable_file = in_file.read()

root = Tk()
text = Text(root)
text.insert(1.0, readable_file)
text.pack(expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
root.mainloop()
```

I could access locations in text file. How can I "slice" this string `readable_file` with the initial `line.char` and the final `line.char`?

Is there a different way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use the [`get`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.get-method) method of your `Text` widget using the `Text` widget's indices:

```
>>> from tkinter import *
>>> root = Tk()
>>> text = Text(root)
>>> text.insert("end", "Hello world, how are you?")
>>> text.pack(fill="both", expand=1)
>>> text.get("1.0", "1.4")
'Hell'
>>> text.get("1.4", "end") 
'o world, how are you?\n'
>>> text.get("2.0", "end")  # because there's just one line
''
>>> text.get("1.7", "end-1c")  # without the newline at the end
'orld, how are you?'
```

This is the only way I know to do it easily. You could also get all the text (again using `Text` widget's indices) and store in in a string, and then manipulate the string, but it is more work.